# Android Studio & Kotlin: ListView won't get fixated below app_bar using anchor in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: xml, android-studio, listview, kotlin

Hey fellow programmers,

there's a listView I have that I can't fixate below the appbar in a CoordinatorLayout (using layout_anchor).

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".UserSettings">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_and_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="speichern und zurück" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/username" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_user_settings" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/switchUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

While in the layout's text editing view there seems to be no problem, in the Design view the layout_anchor "@id/app_bar" also throws the error unexpected resource type: "id" expected: string

I tried changing `android:fitsSystemWindows` to false but this didn't help.

I'm thankful for any help :)

Comment: think that you are missing the behavior for the listview app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: Yes, you're right, thats actually the solution!
Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the behavior for the listview is missing, just add:

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`